# Visual Studio 2019 publish project does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, publishing

I want to publish my WPF application in Visual Studio 2019 (Version: 16.9.5).

I right-click on the project in the solution explorer, click on `Publish` and a new tab opens. The tab should show the settings for publishing, but is loading endlessly.

I tried with a blank/new console application, but I have the same problem.

Steps to publish: [Tutorial: Publish a .NET console application using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio)

**EDIT**: The Visual Studio Log regarding to the publisher:

```
Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.ServiceActivationFailedException: Activating the &quot;Microsoft.Publish.Framework.PublishProfilesService (1.0)&quot; service failed. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException: No exports were found that match the constraint: &#x000A;&#x0009;ContractName&#x0009;Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.IPublishProfilesService&#x000A;&#x0009;RequiredTypeIdentity&#x0009;Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.IPublishProfilesService&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.PublishProfilesService.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.VisualStudio.PublishPackage.&lt;&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;b__7_1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ServiceBroker.GlobalBrokeredServiceContainer.ProfferedServiceFactory.&lt;InvokeFactoryAsync&gt;d__32.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ServiceBroker.GlobalBrokeredServiceContainer.ProfferedServiceFactory.&lt;GetProxyAsync&gt;d__28`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.ServiceBroker.GlobalBrokeredServiceContainer.View.&lt;GetProxyAsync&gt;d__19`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache or repairing VS using the installer?

Comment: The issue occurred in VS19 v16.9.4, so I just updated to 16.9.5, but same issue. I also deleted cache, but same

Comment: did you try to repair?

Comment: Yes, I tried. No effect

Comment: Did you try checking VS logs? Any extensions enabled? I also read that AntiVirus could cause VS to hang..not certain though as I've not experienced this.

Comment: No extension active. I deactivated AntiVirus SW, no effect. Log depending the publisher: `Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.ServiceActivationFailedException: Activating the &quot;Microsoft.Publish.Framework.PublishProfilesService (1.0)&quot; service failed. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException: No exports were found that match the constraint: &#x000A;&#x0009;ContractName&#x0009;Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.IPublishProfilesService&#x000A;&#x0009;RequiredTypeIdentity&#x0009;Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.IPublishProfilesService&#x000D;&#x000A; ...`

Answer (score 0):

if you think it is a bug you can creating an issue [here](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues)

or you You can try alternatively using cli [publish-with-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) :

```sh
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Comment: Yes this works. But the publishing tool provides an installer which can install .Net if not already installed. This solution does not, don't?

Comment: I tried on a machine without .Net. If you start the Application, it says something like this: ".Net is required. Do you want to download?". It's not perfect, but works.

Comment: you can use [self contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment)
***dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained true***

and specified the [RID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)